# PHP - Laravel: My submit button does not work

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I'm developing a web app and currently coding a form. For some reason, even after filling up the form, it does not submit at first, I have to refresh the page for it to submit to the back-end.

Here's the code for the form:

```html
@extends('layout.admin')

@section('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/vendor/bootstrap-float-label.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/vendor/select2.min.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/vendor/select2-bootstrap.min.css')}}">
@endsection

@section('content')
    @if (session()->has('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success rounded" role="alert">{{ session('success') }}</div>
    @endif
    @if(session()->has('error'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger rounded" role="alert">{{ session('error') }}</div>
    @endif
    <form method="post" id="form" action="{{ isset($cliente) ? route('admin.clientes.update', $cliente) : route('admin.clientes.inserir') }}" class="form bv-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
        @csrf
        @if(isset($cliente))
            @method('PUT')
        @endif
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 form-group has-float-label position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="tipo-cliente">Tipo Cliente: </label> <br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="tipo" id="p_fisica" value="1" @if(isset($cliente) && $cliente->tipo === 1) checked @endif> Pessoa Fisica <br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="tipo" id="p_juridica" value="2" @if(isset($cliente) && $cliente->tipo === 2) checked @endif> Pessoa Juridica
                                </div>                        
                                <div class="col form-group position-relative error-l-50 has-float-label" id="div_nome">
                                    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->nome : old('nome') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col form-group position-relative error-l-50 has-float-label" id="div_cpf">
                                    <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" class="form-control cpf" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cpf : old('cpf') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 form-group has-float-label position-relative error-l-50" id="div_sexo">
                                    <label for="sexo">Sexo</label><br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="sexo_masc" value="1" @if(isset($cliente) && $cliente->sexo === 1) checked @endif> Masculino <br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="sexo" id="sexo_fem" value="2" @if(isset($cliente) && $cliente->sexo === 1) checked @endif> Feminino
                                </div>
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50 display-invisible" id="div_cnpj">
                                    <label for="cnpj">CNPJ</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cnpj" id="cnpj" class="form-control cnpj" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cnpj : old('cnpj') }}" onkeyup="isValidCNPJ(this)">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col form-group position-relative error-l-50 has-float-label display-invisible" id="div_razao">
                                    <label for="razao_social">Razao Social</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="razao_social" class="form-control" id="razao_social" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->razao_social : old('razao_social') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- row end -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 form-group position-relative error-l-50 has-float-label">
                                    <label for="empresa_filial">Empresa Filial: </label>
                                    <select name="empresa_filial" class="form-control select2-single">
                                        @foreach($empresas as $empresa)
                                            <option value="{{$empresa->id}}" @if(isset($cliente) && $cliente->empresa_filial === $empresa->id) selected @endif>{{$empresa->nome_empresa}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->email : old('email') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cod_pais_2">Pais</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cod_pais_2" class="form-control cod_pais_2" required value="+55" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cod_pais_2 : old('cod_pais_2') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="telefone" class="form-control telefone" id="telefone" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->telefone : old('telefone') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- row end -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2 has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cep">CEP</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cep" class="form-control cep" id="cep" name="cep" required value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cep : old('cep') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-5 has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="endereco">Endereco</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="endereco" class="form-control" required id="endereco" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->endereco : old('endereco') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2 has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cod_pais_1">Pais</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cod_pais_1" class="form-control cod_pais_1" required value="+55" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cod_pais_1 : old('cod_pais_1') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3 has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="telefone">Celular</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="celular" class="form-control celular" required value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->celular : old('celular') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- row end -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="complemento">Complemento</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="complemento" required class="form-control" id="complemento" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->complemento : old('complemento') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="ponto_referencia">Ponto de Referencia</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="ponto_referencia" class="form-control" id="ponto_referencia" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->ponto_referencia : old('ponto_referencia') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="bairro">Bairro</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="bairro" class="form-control" required id="bairro" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->bairro : old('bairro') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- row end -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cidade">Cidade</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cidade" required id="cidade" class="form-control" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cidade : old('cidade') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="uf">Estado</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2-single" name="uf" required>
                                        <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
                                        @foreach(\App\Helpers\Helpers::estados() as $estado => $nome)
                                            <option value="{{ $estado }}" @if(isset($cliente) && $cliente->uf === $estado) selected @endif>{{ $nome }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="pais">Pais</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2-single" required id="pais" name="pais" data-width="100%">
                                        @foreach(\App\Helpers\Helpers::paises() as $pais)
                                            <option value="{{ $pais['nome'] }}" @if(isset($cliente) && $cliente->pais === $pais) selected @endif>{{ $pais['nome'] }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- row end -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="observacao">Observacao</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="observacao" class="form-control" id="observacao" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->observacao : old('observacao') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- row end -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="card" style="padding-bottom: 2px">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <h3 style="margin-left:8px">Informacoes de Cobranca</h3>
                            </div><!-- row end -->
                            <div class="row">               
                                <input type="checkbox" name="reciclar_info" id="client-check" style="margin-left:8px" onchange="chargingFields()">
                                <span style="margin: 10px">Usar as mesmas informacoes de endereco para cobranca</span>
                                <hr class="style-six"> <br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cobranca_cnpj">CNPJ</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cobranca_cnpj" onkeyup="isValidCobrancaCNPJ()" class="form-control cnpj" id="cobranca_cnpj" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cobranca_cnpj : old('cobranca_cnpj') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cobranca_razao_social">Razao Social</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cobranca_razao_social" class="form-control" id="cobranca_razao_social" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cobranca_razao_social : old('cobranca_razao_social') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- row end -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cobranca_cep">CEP</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cobranca_cep" class="form-control cep" id="cobranca_cep" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cobranca_cep : old('cobranca_cep') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cobranca_endereco">Endereco</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cobranca_endereco" class="form-control" id="cobranca_endereco" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cobranca_endereco : old('cobranca_endereco') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cobranca_complemento">Complemento</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cobranca_complemento" class="form-control" id="cobranca_complemento" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cobranca_complemento : old('cobranca_complemento') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cobranca_ponto_referencia">Ponto de Referencia</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cobranca_ponto_referencia" id="cobranca_ponto_referencia" class="form-control" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cobranca_ponto_referencia : old('cobranca_ponto_referencia') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cobranca_bairro">Bairro</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cobranca_bairro" class="form-control" id="cobranca_bairro" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cobranca_bairro : old('cobranca_bairro') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cobranca_cidade">Cidade</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cobranca_cidade" id="cobranca_cidade" class="form-control" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cobranca_cidade : old('cobranca_cidade') }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cobranca_uf">Estado</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2-single" name="cobranca_uf" id="cobranca_uf">
                                        <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
                                        @foreach(\App\Helpers\Helpers::estados() as $estado => $nome)
                                            <option value="{{ $estado }}" 
                                                    @if(isset($cliente) && $cliente->cobranca_uf === $estado) selected @endif>{{ $nome }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cobranca_pais">Pais</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2-single" name="cobranca_pais" id="cobranca_pais">
                                        @foreach(\App\Helpers\Helpers::paises() as $pais)
                                            <option value="{{ $pais['nome'] }}" @if(isset($cliente) && $cliente->cobranca_pais === $pais) selected @endif>{{ $pais['nome'] }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- row end -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col has-float-label form-group position-relative error-l-50">
                                    <label for="cobranca_observacao">Observacao</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cobranca_observacao" class="form-control" id="cobranca_observacao" value="{{ isset($cliente) ? $cliente->cobranca_observacao : old('cobranca_observacao') }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <button type="submit" id="save-button" class="btn btn-primary float-left" style="margin-top: 10px">
                        @if(isset($cliente))
                            Salvar
                        @else
                            Adicionar
                        @endif
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- row end -->
        </div>
    </form>
@endsection

@section('js')
    <script src="{{ asset('js/vendor/jquery.validate/jquery.validate.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/vendor/jquery.validate/additional-methods.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/vendor/select2.full.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        const addressApiUrl = "{{ route('pega.endereco') }}";
    </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/cliente_form.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sent = false;

        function isValidCobrancaCNPJ() {
            var strCNPJ = $("#cobranca_cnpj").val();
            console.log(strCNPJ);
            // Caso o CEP não esteja nesse formato ele é inválido!
            var objER = /^[0-9]{14}$/;

            strCNPJ = Trim(strCNPJ);

            if(strCNPJ.length > 0) {
                if(objER.test(strCNPJ) && !sent) {
                    sent = true;
                    formReadOnly(true);

                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: "{{ route('pega.cnpj.interno') }}",
                        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                        data: {cnpj: strCNPJ},
                        success: function (data) {
                            if(!data.error) {
                                $.notify({
                                    // options
                                    message: 'CNPJ verificado!'
                                },{
                                    // settings
                                    type: 'success'
                                });

                                $('#cobranca_razao_social').val(data.razao_social);
                                $('#cobranca_cep').val(data.cep);
                                $('#cobranca_endereco').val(data.endereco);
                                $('#cobranca_bairro').val(data.bairro);
                                $('#cobranca_cidade').val(data.cidade);
                                $('#cobranca_uf').val(data.uf);
                                $('#cobranca_endereco').focus();

                                sent = false;

                                $('#form').bootstrapValidator('destroy');
                                $('#form').data('bootstrapValidator', null);
                                $('#form').bootstrapValidator();
                            }else{
                                $.notify({
                                    // options
                                    message: data.msg
                                },{
                                    // settings
                                    type: 'danger'
                                });
                                sent = false;
                            }
                            formReadOnly(false);
                        },
                        error: function (msg) {
                            sent = false;
                            formReadOnly(false);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        function Trim(strTexto)
        {
            // Substitúi os espaços vazios no inicio e no fim da string por vazio.
            return strTexto.replace(/\D/g, "");
        }

        function isValidCNPJ() {
            var strCNPJ = $("#cnpj").val();
            console.log(strCNPJ);
            // Caso o CEP não esteja nesse formato ele é inválido!
            var objER = /^[0-9]{14}$/;

            strCNPJ = Trim(strCNPJ);

            if(strCNPJ.length > 0)
            {
                if(objER.test(strCNPJ) && !sent)
                {
                    sent = true;
                    formReadOnly(true);

                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: "{{ route('pega.cnpj.interno') }}",
                        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                        data: {cnpj: strCNPJ},
                        success: function (data)
                        {
                            if(!data.error)
                            {
                                $.notify({
                                    // options
                                    message: 'CNPJ verificado!'
                                },{
                                    // settings
                                    type: 'success'
                                });

                                $('#razao_social').val(data.razao_social);
                                $('#cep').val(data.cep);
                                $('#endereco').val(data.endereco);
                                $('#bairro').val(data.bairro);
                                $('#cidade').val(data.cidade);
                                $('#uf').val(data.uf);
                                $('#endereco').focus();

                                sent = false;

                                $('#form').bootstrapValidator('destroy');
                                $('#form').data('bootstrapValidator', null);
                                $('#form').bootstrapValidator();
                            }else{
                                $.notify({
                                    // options
                                    message: data.msg
                                },{
                                    // settings
                                    type: 'danger'
                                });
                                sent = false;
                            }
                            formReadOnly(false);
                        },
                        error: function (msg) {
                            sent = false;
                            formReadOnly(false);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
@endsection
```

Controller:

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Models\Empresa;
    use App\Models\Cliente;

    class ClienteController extends Controller
    {

        public function index() {
            $data['clientes'] = Cliente::all();

            return view('admin.clientes.index', $data);
        }

        public function addCliente() {
            $data['empresas'] = Empresa::all();

            return view('admin.clientes.cadastro',$data);
        }

        public function insert(Request $request) {
            $cliente = new Cliente;

            $cliente->empresa_filial = $request->empresa_filial;

            $cliente->tipo = $request->tipo;
            $cliente->email = $request->email;
              
            if ($request->tipo == 1) {
                $cliente->nome = $request->nome;
                $cliente->cpf = $request->cpf;
            
                $cliente->cnpj = $cliente->razao_social = "";
            } else {
                $cliente->cnpj = $request->cnpj;
                $cliente->razao_social = $request->razao_social;

                $cliente->nome = $cliente->cpf = "";
            }

            //had to resume code due to body limitations, but basically what is above for other fields
            $cliente->save();

            return redirect()->back()->with(['success' => 'Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!']);
        }

        public function update($identificacao, Request $request) {
            

            $cliente->save();
        }
    }
```

I'm currently using Laravel as a framework and have tried everything (@csrf, csrf_field(), adding a token via hidden input), nothing works, I'm lost.

Also, by checking the browser's network activity, POST methods for getting information such as address are working fine inside the form, only problem being the submit button.

EDIT: The routes:

```php
Route::prefix('clientes')->group(function() {
        Route::view('/1/detalhes', 'admin.clientes.detalhes')->name('admin.clientes.detalhes');
        Route::get('/', 'ClienteController@index')->name('admin.clientes.index');
        Route::get('/cadastro', 'ClienteController@addCliente')->name('admin.clientes.cadastro');
        Route::get('/atualizar/{cliente}', 'ClienteController@atualizarCliente')->name('admin.clientes.atualizar');
        Route::get('/{cliente}', 'ClienteController@delete')->name('admin.clientes.delete');
        Route::put('/atualizar/{cliente}', 'ClienteController@update')->name('admin.clientes.update');
        Route::post('/cadastro', 'ClienteController@insert')->name('admin.clientes.inserir');
    });
```

Comment: _only problem being the submit button._ what you mean??

Comment: If refreshing the page is what causes the form to submit, my guess would be there is no valid post route setup in the routes/web.php file. Start there and make sure the form's action has a valid post route setup.

Comment: @Berto99 I meant that all the other POST routes like validating address and validating information from the person are working fine, just the submit button is not working at all unless I refresh the page

Comment: @EricBrown the routes seems to be pointing correctly, I can put them here if you want to.